Voltage across current source?
Consider the circuit below. If I apply KVL, I get V=5. If I use superposition then V=-5. What have I done wrong?

Math error, specifically sign error.

When applying superposition, you must sum the variables of interest, Voltages here. I feel you have summed the current of \$ i = 0 \$ and a voltage of \$-5 \text{ V}\$. If you apply superposition correctly, the open circuit voltage would be \$ 10 \textbf{ V}\$, since no current is flowing out of the voltage source:

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
Next, in the last schematic you have, the voltage of interest is -5 V, because a current is being forced to flow from the resistor:

simulate this circuit
The final summation would then simply be \$ V_{out} = 10 + (-5) = +5 \textbf{ V}\$.

Yes it was a silly mistake. I wrote i=0 to indicate that the voltage drop across the resistor will be 0 and hence by mistake thought that the voltage drop across the current source will also be 0. Very sorry and I thank you.

If the current source is 1 amp then 1 amp is flowing through the 5 Ω resistor and, that means there's 5 volts across it (ohm's law) and, in turn, that means there's 5 volts across the 1 amp current source. 5 + 5 = 10.
If the resistor was 1 Ω then there would be 9 volts across the current source. If the resistor was 20 Ω then there would be 20 volts across it and -10 volts across the current source.
It's a simple case of ohm's law and adding up the volts to make ten (some people call that Kirchhoff's voltage law but, it's really too basic to be profound enough for a proper name in my book).
